# Flutter WebView file upload does not working to android app ,IOS app also ok. Anyone can help me how to solve this problem?

Tags: flutter, webview-flutter

Here I have added my webview code in bellow. Website perfectly loaded but i couldn't camera & file chooser option to upload server.

WebView(
initialUrl: '',///url

```
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,

            onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) async {
              _controller.complete(webViewController);
            },
            onProgress: (value) {

              if (value == 100) {
                isPageLoading = false;
              }
              setState(() {});

            },
            navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {

              print('RequestedUrl=>${request.url}');

              if (request.url.contains(
                  

              }

              return NavigationDecision.navigate;
            },
            onPageStarted: (String url) async {
             
            },
            onPageFinished: (String url) {
              print('Page finished loading: $url');
              //readJS();
            },
            gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
            javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>{
              _toasterJavascriptChannel(context),
            },
          );
```

Comment: checkout stackoverflow.com/a/77155112/1979347 for fixing file upload issue on Android using webview

Answer (score 2):

I have used [flutter_inappwebveiew](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview)

Make sure you have added permission for Uploads.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIDEO_CAPTURE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUDIO_CAPTURE" />
```

In Manifest

```
 <provider
        android:name="com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_inappwebview.InAppWebViewFileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter_inappwebview.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

Comment: I already used it .But some url has been close after load website inside of InAppWebView

Url: https://ferche.app/ (When this url load in InAppWebView then this page has  auto navigate  to previous page) .I don't find this issue.
Could you tell me what kind of the issue?

Comment: I can't get your question